# Using hibernate with JavaFx on a Maven project?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, javafx

First of all, I hope you all safe and healthy, thanks for your help as advance.

Me and my friends still learning java and start a Maven project with JavaFX and now we are learning also hibernate framework and we would like to use it with JavaFX but there is a problem that we couldn't handle.

(I already search and read about this kind of topic but I think there isn't my question's answer. If it's sorry for that.)

Firstly, we started the project, which is an application for Cinema reservation, with the only JavaFx and I was responsible for the login part of the project. Before hibernate, after encrypted the information I was storing them in a file, and all work very well. After hibernate I tried to create a local database and combine them for storing all information but when I created a module-info.java for Hibernate I get an error that mentions other fx libraries need to be mentioned in module-info.java then I also added them in it and remove from the pom.xml because handling to reading the same libraries from the 2 places.

My questions about the process of what I am doing as follows;

-Do I making a logical mistake related usage of the module-info.java or pom.xml
-If both could be in the same project, what should I do
-What is the most effective way to implement hibernate?
-Should I use Multi-module implementation for this kind of app?

Here is my pom.xml and module-info.java;
pom.xml with module-info.java:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>be.javaHeverlee</groupId>
    <artifactId>CinemaApplication</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cinemaBookingSystem</name>
    <description>starter project for javaFX</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <javafx.version>13.0.1</javafx.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.4.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mySql.version>8.0.19</mySql.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JAVA FX -->

        <!-- JFOENIX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jfoenix</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfoenix</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DATABASE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mySql.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FONT_AWESOME -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
            <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
            <version>8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>

        <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                    implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>


</project>
```

and Module-info.java:

```java
open module CinemaApplication {
    requires lombok;

    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires java.sql;
    requires net.bytebuddy;
    requires java.xml.bind;
    requires com.fasterxml.classmate;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires java.desktop;
    requires com.jfoenix;
    requires java.prefs;
    requires java.persistence;
}
```

My folders:

[image: image of folder structure]

[image: image of folder structure]

According to my research I can handle to run after changing the maven>runner> choosing the "Delaget IDE build/run actions to Maven"
but still has problems with Maven, cannot build or install(mvn clean install or mvn clean compile) properly.

if I deselect the maven>runner>"Delaget IDE build/run actions to Maven" and try to rebuild and run getting that error:

```
Information:java: compiler message file broken: key=compiler.misc.msg.bug arguments=11.0.6, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}
Information:java: java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module lombok does not read a module that exports org.mapstruct.ap.spi
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.resolveFail(Resolver.java:885)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.checkExportSuppliers(Resolver.java:760)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Resolver.finish(Resolver.java:362)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:141)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:495)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.module.Configuration.resolveAndBind(Configuration.java:299)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file.JavacFileManager.getServiceLoader(JavacFileManager.java:985)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Information:java:   at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain$8.invoke(JavacMain.java:387)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy17.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.getServiceLoader(Unknown Source)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.initProcessorLoader(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:261)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:237)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.instance(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:193)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.initProcessAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1136)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:922)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)
Information:java:   at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.javac.JavacMain.compile(JavacMain.java:207)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compileJava(JavaBuilder.java:486)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.compile(JavaBuilder.java:338)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.doBuild(JavaBuilder.java:263)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.java.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:216)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1328)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1006)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1073)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:967)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:796)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:378)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:178)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:140)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:297)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:130)
Information:java:   at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:232)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
Information:java:   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'CinemaApplication'
Information:javac 11.0.6 was used to compile java sources
Information:16/08/2020, 01:28 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1 s 480 ms
Error:java: Compilation failed: internal java compiler error
```

IntelliJ Ultimate Edition,
MacOs Catalina,
Java 11.

Thank you all,

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add mapstruct-processor dependency to your project for resolving this issue
add this to your dependencies

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and this to your module-info.java

```java
requires org.mapstruct.processor;
```

happy coding... :)

Comment: try changing your module-info.java file contents with this

`module be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem {
    requires lombok;
    requires org.mapstruct.processor;

    // requires ...

    exports be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem;
}`

Comment: I think there is also a problem because the module name and export package is the same?      Information:java: Errors occurred while compiling module 'CinemaApplication'
Information:javac 11.0.6 was used to compile java sources
Information:17/08/2020, 23:31 - Build completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 2 s 236 ms
/Users/admin/IdeaProjects/cinema-reservation-system/src/main/java/module-info.java
Error:(19, 28) java: package is empty or does not exist: be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem

Comment: move your module-info.java file to java folder

Comment: are you sure? i think it is in be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem

Comment: Added a new picture to the main entry that shows the folder structure. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: then you didn't modified it yet

Comment: that's not right. replace all contents with this.   `module be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem { requires lombok; requires org.mapstruct.processor; requires org.hibernate.orm.core; requires java.sql; requires net.bytebuddy; requires java.xml.bind; requires com.fasterxml.classmate; requires javafx.graphics; requires javafx.fxml; requires javafx.media; requires javafx.controls; requires java.desktop; requires java.prefs; requires java.persistence; requires com.jfoenix; exports be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem; }`

Comment: did you notice that open module CinemaApplication  and module be.javaHeverlee.cinemaBookingSystem in first line?

Comment: Yes, of course. Also, I declare in the pom.xml as CinemaApplication. That's why I tried with that too.